# Laravel : Toggling Display using the value of a Controller variable

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have a blade file with the following section of code.

```
@if($search_tags)
<div>
    <hr>
    <form action="/search-page/" method="get">
        <label for='searchstr'><b>Key in Tags : </b></label>
        <input type='text' id='searchstr' name='searchstr' class='form-control'><br>
        <div class="center">
            <input type='submit' name='search' class="btn btn-success" value = "Search"/>
            <button type='button' class="btn btn-success">
              <a href="{{ url('searchn') }}" style='color:white'>N</a></button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <hr>
</div>
@else
<div>
    <hr>
    <form action="/search-page/" method="get">
        <label for='searchstr'><b>Key in Name : </b></label>
        <input type='text' id='searchstr' name='searchstr' class='form-control'><br>
        <div class="center">
            <input type='submit' name='search' class="btn btn-success" value = "Search"/>
            <button type='button' class="btn btn-success">
              <a href="{{ url('searchn') }}" style='color:white'>T</a></button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <hr>
</div>
@endif
```

Which div gets displayed depends on the value of variable $search_tags.  The boolean value of $search_tags is changed by clicking on the button (below the submit input).

I am using Laravel 7 and the route for 'searchn' is recorded as

```
// toggle search and search tags
Route::get('/searchn', 'PostController@toggle_search_tags');
```

The PostController function toggle_search_tags is

```
public function toggle_search_tags()
{
    $this->search_tags = ! $this->search_tags;
    if (Auth::check()) {

        return view('home')->withTitle($title)->withPosts($posts)->with('search_tags', $this->search_tags);
    } else {

        return view('home')->withTitle($title)->withPosts($posts)->with('search_tags', $this->search_tags);
    }
}
```

Apparently, I can only click the button once i.e. the blade file will only change the div in the view only once.  After that, nothing happens.  There is no change in the value of $search_tags and hence no change in the blade file.

One more thing.  When I first start up the app, the url on the browser is 'localhost:8000'.  At this url, by clicking the button, the url changes to 'localhost:8000/searchn'.  After this, as with the variables and blade file, the url does not change from 'localhost:8000/searchn'.  It feels that I am missing something basic but I can't figure out what.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I believe you are mistaken to use $search_tags as a class property, because it's value is set to default every time the controller is called and executed, so each time only one div get displayed over and over again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I made $search_tags an integer. It went from 0 to 1. It never went back to 0 but stayed at 1. If it were constantly instantiated, it would go back to 0 wouldn't it?

Comment: In your controller class, I assume you initialize it to 0. So, when you visit the url, the controller is called and sets the $search_tags to 0, then when you reach the toggle_search_tags() function in that controller, the value is then set to 1. So, you will see the div associated with value of 1 all the time.

Comment: Thanks. Yes you are right.  If this isn't the way then I will have to figure something else out. But if this is true, that means the Controller is instantiated every time a call to one of its functions is made!

Comment: that is true, controller gets initiated every single time it's called. I suggest you use parameters in your controller to know which do div to display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the PHP in Laravel framework is totally the wrong direction.  Me bad.  The solution is to implement in Javascript swapping the contents of a div with

```
elem = document.getElementById('searchport');
elem.innerHTML = 'stuff that goes into the div';
```

The logic that decides on which screen also goes easily with JS.
Inconvenience caused regretted.